# How do I assign values to properties using hexadecimal notation using Apex?

Tags: apex

Newby question:

I'm in the process of porting some code from another language to Apex.

How do I assign values to properties/variables using hexadecimal notation?

Eg:

```
public class myClass() {

   void mymethod() {
      Integer redColor = 0xFF0000; //editor  doesn't like this
      //-- other code continues....
   }

}
```

Note: I'd prefer not to use a conversion function such as:

```
Integer i = StringHexToIntFuntion(h);
```

as this code needs to be very efficient and will be executed repeatedly during processing.

I could manually convert the hex to decimal and then just input that, but there's a ton of code, so I'm hoping there's an obvious way that I've just missed.

Comment: What kind of logic is this number driving? Why does base 10 not work?

Comment: Base 10 does work, but the code being ported contains constants in base 16. There are too many values to convert manually (to base 10) - but that's beside the point. For the future it would be useful if I knew how I could directly enter hex values. I'm beginning to think its not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike many other languages, Apex Code does not support Base 2 (binary), Base 8 (octal), or Base 16 (hexadecimal) directly in source code. Additionally, there's no built-in hexadecimal-to-integer function, either. You would need to create some sort of hex-string-to-integer function, as you've described.

Comment: @nspire Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't tell us this directly, so we can only realize this by observing the omission of the documentation saying we can write non-base-10 values in source code. It's kind of an odd limitation, given that Apex Code has its roots in Java, which does support these kinds of values.

Answer (score -1):

```
public with sharing class HexToBin {
private String code;
public String result;
Map<String, String> hexToBinMap = new Map<String, String>{'0'=>'0000','1'=>'0001','2'=>'0010','3'=>'0011','4'=>'0100','5'=>'0101','6'=>'0110','7'=>'0111','8'=>'1000','9'=>'1001','A'=>'1010','B'=>'1011','C'=>'1100','D'=>'1101','E'=>'1110','F'=>'1111'}; 
public HexToBin(String code) {
    this.code = code;
    result = getResult(code);
}

private String hexToBin(String hex){
    if(hex.length()==1){
        return hexToBinMap.get(hex);
    }
    return '';
}

private String getResult (String code) {
    String res ='';
    for(Integer i=0; i<code.length(); i++){         
        res =  res + hexToBin(code.substring(i,i+1));
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

Comment: Usage:    
String hexStr = '10ABF';
String result = new HexToBin(hexStr).result;


//result = 00010000101010111111

Comment: Please do not post `code dump answers` as they do not tend to be usfeull for the community in general.

Comment: Please edit your own answer rather than adding comments